# How to load data from Lake database into Synapse Notebook through Pipeline?

Tags: etl, azure-synapse

I have a Spark Datalake in Synapse in which i have 6 tables. The data in all tables i have loaded from 6 different csv files. These csv files have been loaded and updated manually by third party if some new data comes. In future also the data in these files will be loaded manually. File name will always be same.

Currently in my synapse Notebook i am using those 6 tables data for transforming a new file that came for processing and i have transformed one file by using Pyspark in my synapse notebook. But In my case i am manually giving the file name in my code which is connected to Synapse ADLS as our Source files are coming there but in future the this process will be automated. The Code Should work for every new Source File that came for Processing .

My Question here is about the 6 Tables which are in my Spark Datalake when we create a ETL process for it in Synapse and load my code in Notebook Activity will at that time the 6 tables i am using in my Code will able to read data from those tables and Suppose if some new data been updatedto those 6 tables will i able to see changes in my tables and same in my transformed file also.

This is the Code which i am using for loading data from one of the table from my lake database into my notebook currently

```
%%pyspark
df_IndustryData = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM DATA.Industry_data")
Display(df_Industry_data)
```

Thanks in advance for your responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I think you may find this applicable.

Lake Database (Spark) Tables are persisted in ADLS as a folder of Parquet files, and then exposed as External Tables. You can then query these tables from either your notebook or Serverless SQL.

A Lake Database Table is a therefore a logical schema overlaid on top of the physical files in Storage. So whenever you update/overwrite the underlying data [the physical parquet files], the Lake Database Table (External Table) will show the current data in the files.